# insertion in Postgres database using psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am  inserting data into Postgresql database table by using psycopg2 
library, but I am getting an error in the insertion command. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

```
def t_b():  
    table = 'create table {} (Title serial, Link char(50), logo_link 
    char(50), Description Text)'.format(name)  
    cur.execute(table)  
    print("Table created :", name)  

def insertion(name, data):  
    data_s = ",".join(data)
    ins = 'insert into {} (Title,Link,logo_link,Description)values({})'.format(name, data_s)  
    cur.execute(ins)  
    conn.commit()  

def main():  
    t_b("ONE")  
    dd = ('abc', '123', 'INsyustriesz', '<htt:ps>' )  
    insertion("ONE", dd)  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
    cur.execute()
```

And the error message appears:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ":"  
LINE 1: ... logo_link, Description) values(abc,123,INsyustriesz,htt:ps)
```

and data is not inserted

Comment: Let psycopg2 format the query: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because you're not including single-quotes in the `values` section of the query.  You use single-quotes in `dd`, but those are to help Python interpret them as strings.  I wouldn't recommending stringing everything together in `data_s` via a `join`, but actually specifying each element in the `VALUES` section:

```
    ins = 'insert into {} (Title,Link,logo_link,Description)values({},{},{},{})'.format((name + data))
```

Comment: sir its not working yet sir kindly can you tell me why we are adding(concatenate) name and data this commands also throwing error.